# Pagination not showing page numbers in ListView

Tags: python, django

I'm was able to get pagination to work fine in a function based view, but now I re-factored everything into a class based view and now the pagination numbers are not showing.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import EmployeeProfiles


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ppm/ppm.html'
    paginate_by = 5  # Show 5 profiles per page

    def get(self, request):
        profiles_set = EmployeeProfiles.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(profiles_set, self.paginate_by) 
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            profiles = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            profiles = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            profiles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {
            'profiles_set': profiles_set,
            'title': 'Employee Profiles'
         }

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**ppm.html**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if profiles_set.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ profiles_set.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ profiles_set.number }} of {{ profiles_set.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if profiles_set.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ profiles_set.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

**Output:** 'Page of . '

I've already looked at the solutions to the similar questions and have tried them and still haven't been able to find a solution. Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you don't need to override `get`. Your code simple enough for default implementation.

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = EmployeeProfiles
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'ppm/ppm.html'
```

Secondly, in template use pagination provided by CBW.

**ppm.html**

```
<table>
{% for profile in object_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ profile.name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<p>
{% if is_paginated %}
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
            <span>Previous</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="disabled">
        <a href="#">
            <span>Previous</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for page in paginator.page_range %}
        <li {% if page == page_obj.number %}class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">
            <span>Next</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li {% if not page_obj.has_next %}class="disabled"{% endif %}>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Next</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}
</p>
```

And a little advice: It is better to use the singular for the model name.

Comment: So I don't need the get method at all? I just need those 3 lines that you demonstrated in views.py? I tried that but it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you need only those 3 line. Did you change ppm.html?

Comment: I did change ppm.html but when I just added those 3 lines and removed  everything else the table just disappeared.

Comment: OK, now the pagination buttons are working but the table is not showing

Comment: Thank you, it worked!!! But why? Why object_list and page_obj? Also what did you mean when you said it's better to use the singular for the model name?

Comment: page_obj - it's a paginator, object_list - list of models.
I mean "EmployeeProfile" not "EmployeeProfiles".

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. You've been a tremendous help. Classes are deceptively simple when compared to function based views. So you mean I should rename my model from "EmployeeProfiles" to "EmployeeProfile", why is that if you don't mind me asking. Is it by convention?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. It's by convention. Thanks.